# Modelling document sharing permissions with NoSQL

Tags: nosql

I'd like to use NoSQL databases for the first time and was going to use MongoDB.  I have a project where an employee with `@employeed_id` can go to a web app and get a list of documents that he can read.  If this were a relational database, I might begin my SQL statement like this to fetch all the documents he has read access to (I'll explain in plain english what I'm trying to achieve next):

```
SELECT * FROM t_document
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM t_user
    WHERE t_user.user_id = t_document.author_id
    AND t_user.user_id = @employee_id
) OR EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM t_user
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM t_document_share
        WHERE t_document_share.user_id = t_user.user_id
        AND t_document_share.read_access = 1
    )
    AND t_document.company_id = t_user.company_id
    AND t_user.user_id = @employee_id
) OR EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM t_user
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM t_document_group_share
        WHERE t_document_group_share.read_access = 1
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM t_user_group
            WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 FROM t_user
                WHERE t_user.user_id = t_user_group.user_id
                AND t_user.user_id = @employee_id
                ...
                ...
            )
        )

    )
)
```

Essentially, what I'm saying is get me all documents where at least one of these conditions apply:

- I am the author of the document
- the document has been shared with me, I have read access, and the document is owned by a company that I am employed at
- the document has been shared with a group that I belong to.  The group has read access to the document.  Both I, the group, and the document belongs to the same company

After some quick online research, I read opinions that my use case is not meant for NoSQL.  All these sub queries (and potentially joins) to investigate relationships between different entities is cumbersome to do in NoSQL.  **So my question is, can someone confirm if using NoSQL to solve my problem is like trying to make a fish climb a tree?**  If so, then I will look for other projects to practice NoSQL on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll answer my own question until someone gives a better answer.

When the relationships between entities are known and important to preserve, these relationships are costly to implement and enforce with a NoSQL database.  Looking at the relationships between entities is easy to do with a single SQL statement that is comprised of more sub queries and joins.  Doing something similar with lookups or other javascript/json programmatic instructions is cumbersome and likely to be substantially more computationally intensive when compared with a relational database/SQL approach.

Hence, using a NoSQL database in a situation where the relationships between many entities are known, important to preserve and important to enforce, is like using a steak knife to chop down a tree.  It can be done, but there are better tools for the job.